# Taking Differences of Records When Status Changes - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have customer records with id, timestamp and status.

```
ID, TS, STATUS
1 10 GOOD
1 20 GOOD
1 25 BAD
1 30 BAD
1 50 BAD
1 600 GOOD
2 40 GOOD
.. ...
```

I am trying to calculate how much time is spent in consecutive BAD statuses (lets imagine order above is correct) per customer. So for customer id=1, 30-25,50-30,600-50 in total 575 seconds was spent in BAD status.

What is the method of doing this in Pandas? If I calculate .diff() on TS, that would give me differences, but how can I tie that 1) to the customer 2) certain status "blocks" for that customer?

Sample data:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
                       'TS':[10,20,25,30,50,600,40],
                       'Status':['G','G','B','B','B','G','G']
                       },
                      columns=['ID','TS','Status'])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2],'TS':[10,20,25,30,50,10,40],'Stat
us':['G','G','B','B','B','B','B']}, columns=['ID','TS','Status'])

In [2]: f = lambda x: x.diff().sum()

In [3]: df['diff'] = df[df.Status=='B'].groupby('ID')['TS'].transform(f)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   ID  TS Status  diff
0   1  10      G   NaN
1   1  20      G   NaN
2   1  25      B    25
3   1  30      B    25
4   1  50      B    25
5   2  10      B    30
6   2  40      B    30
```

Explanation:
Subset the `dataframe` to only those records with the desired Status.  `Groupby` the ID and apply the lambda function `diff().sum()` to each group.  Use `transform` instead of `apply` because `transform` returns an indexed series which you can use to assign to a new column 'diff'.

EDIT: New response to account for expanded question scope.

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   ID   TS Status
0   1   10      G
1   1   20      G
2   1   25      B
3   1   30      B
4   1   50      B
5   1  600      G
6   2   40      G

In [2]: df['shift'] = -df['TS'].diff(-1)

In [3]: df['diff'] = df[df.Status=='B'].groupby('ID')['shift'].transform('sum')
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   ID   TS Status  shift  diff
0   1   10      G     10   NaN
1   1   20      G      5   NaN
2   1   25      B      5   575
3   1   30      B     20   575
4   1   50      B    550   575
5   1  600      G   -560   NaN
6   2   40      G    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hi - what do I do for the transition 50 BAD to 600 GOOD? I still want to count 550 in this sum..

Comment: I've edited my response to try to account for your example and using your dataframe.

Comment: very smart, you changed diff(1) to diff(-1) so that diff would be taken between i and i-1, but then the signs were all negative, hence -diff(-1).

Comment: may want to consider the effect of calculating diff() on an ungrouped dataframe. i.e., what if the row with shift==-560 was bad?

Comment: crewbum is right, my solution does not cover those cases.  His answer is the better one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution to separately aggregate each contiguous block of bad status (part 2 of your question?).

```
In [5]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                               'TS':[10,20,25,30,50,600,650,670,40,50,60],
                               'Status':['G','G','B','B','B','G','B','B','G','B','B']
                               },
                               columns=['ID','TS','Status'])

In [6]: grp = df.groupby('ID')

In [7]: def status_change(df):
   ...:         return (df.Status.shift(1) != df.Status).astype(int)
   ...: 

In [8]: df['BlockId'] = grp.apply(lambda df: status_change(df).cumsum())

In [9]: df['Duration'] = grp.TS.diff().shift(-1)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
    ID   TS Status  BlockId  Duration
0    1   10      G        1        10
1    1   20      G        1         5
2    1   25      B        2         5
3    1   30      B        2        20
4    1   50      B        2       550
5    1  600      G        3        50
6    1  650      B        4        20
7    1  670      B        4       NaN
8    2   40      G        1        10
9    2   50      B        2        10
10   2   60      B        2       NaN

In [11]: df[df.Status == 'B'].groupby(['ID', 'BlockId']).Duration.sum()
Out[11]: 
ID  BlockId
1   2          575
    4           20
2   2           10
Name: Duration
```